# How can I sync music from Ubuntu 14.04 to my Ubuntu Phone (bq Aquaris)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, rhythmbox, banshee

I have an bq Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu edition. I just bought a 32 GB SD card, and now I wanted to sync my music collection from the desktop to the phone. When I plug in the phone with USB, it is recognized as a MTP device. I can browse the phone and the SD card.

However, both Rhythmbox and Banshee fail to sync with the phone. Rhythmbox doesn’t find the device at all. Banshee finds it (sometimes, though it’s a bit shaky). But when I sync my library, it doesn’t really transfer anything (and tends to crash).

I guess I could move the files to the phone’s storage, but that’s not exactly comfortable. Is there a way to sync my music collection to the Ubuntu phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sync music to your latest BQ requires an update to the library libmtp.

As I write this, the ubuntu developers have not backported a patch they have added to the latest vivid sources to support the BQ phone.

Thus, I have done [just this](https://launchpad.net/~fossfreedom/+archive/ubuntu/libmtp) - re-rolled the vivid libmtp sources and made this available via a PPA for Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 users.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/libmtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

To reverse this:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:fossfreedom/libmtp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did help indeed, though I had somewhat mixed results: 

* In Banshee, the behaviour is the same as before, it sometimes recognizes the device, but fails to sync.
* In Rhythmbox, it now finds the device and seems to be ready to sync, but the storage of the device is too small. I guess this is related to sync not using the SD card, and it would be good to be able to configure that. But that is probably a separate issue.

Comment: @Frederik - sync'ing to a SD Card is a common issue - its not a libmtp issue but an app issue.  For the BQ phone, this question has been asked - http://askubuntu.com/questions/601942/sync-music-to-bq-ubuntu-sd-card-with-rhythmbox