# Sync music to bq ubuntu sd card with rhythmbox

Tags: ubuntu-touch, rhythmbox

I've installed new libmtp (ubuntu 14.04) from there (https://launchpad.net/~fossfreedom/+archive/ubuntu/libmtp) and rhythmbox now can view bq device and sync music but there's a problem... syncs to phone and is ignoring sd, syncing all to Music folder in phone. Is possible to sync only to sd with rythmbox? I've tried to create link from Music folder in phone to Music folder in sd but don't work.

Comment: That's the problem with the application.  Please file a bug about it. As an alternative, you can simply run `ssh server` (& thus `SFTP`) & sync your music with `rsync` over SFTP.